# C# Comparing Two Custom Lists

Tags: c#, compare, custom-lists

I have run into a situation where I need to compare two different lists to each other and I am wondering what the best method is for doing this?  I thought something like this would work but it doesn't and I can't figure out why.  The Linq query is returning records it shouldn't.  This is my first run at trying to figure something like this out so it is undoubtedly messy.

```
 private static List<ColumnDefinition> FindTableStructureUpdates(List<ColumnDefinition> colDefs, List<ColumnDefinition> tblCols)
    {
        List<ColumnDefinition> ColsToUpdate = new List<ColumnDefinition>();

        for (int i = 0; i < colDefs.Count; ++i)
        {
            string colDefName = colDefs[i].ColName;
            string colDefDataType = colDefs[i].ColType;
            string colDefAttribute = colDefs[i].ColAttributes;

            var query = from tbl in tblCols
                        where tbl.ColName != colDefName && tbl.ColType != colDefDataType && tbl.ColAttributes != colDefAttribute
                        select new { colDefName, colDefDataType, colDefAttribute };

            if (query.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (var item in query)
                {
                    ColsToUpdate.Add(new ColumnDefinition(item.colDefName, item.colDefDataType, item.colDefAttribute));
                }
            }
        }

        return ColsToUpdate;
```

Any suggestions would be great.

Thanks.

IEquatable Implementation??

```
 #region IEquatable<ColumnDefinition> Members

    public bool Equals(ColumnDefinition other)
    {
        if (this.ColName.Equals(other.ColName) && this.ColType.Equals(other.ColType) && this.ColAttributes.Equals(other.ColAttributes))
            return true;

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a back end SQLite database and I am trying to write a method to compare what the current table structure is to what I have coded in another method so if I make an update to the table in my code the physical table.  I couldn't think of an easier way to do this.

Comment: Only a list of "updated"? No list for "added" and "removed"? Does this mean that we can assume that the two lists always contain the same number of items?

Comment: Why did you choose SQLite? Have you considered something like [DBLinq](http://code.google.com/p/dblinq2007/) which can give you support for Linq-to-SQL for SQLite? (Unfortunately it's not production stable though.)

Comment: The lists would not always contain the same number of items because if I was adding a column to the database then colDefs would have one more item then tblCols.  Sorry the naming of ColsToUpdate is misleading.

Comment: I chose SQLite because this app needs be able to have a database which can be located anywhere (like out on a network drive) and not betied to a server like SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you use `Enumerable.Except` ?

> ```
> public static IEnumerable<TSource> Except<TSource>(
>     this IEnumerable<TSource> first,
>     IEnumerable<TSource> second
> )
> ```

More [details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx).

An example tested in [Snippet Compiler](http://www.sliver.com/dotnet/SnippetCompiler/)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class ColumnDefinition : IEquatable<ColumnDefinition>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Attr { get; set; }

    public ColumnDefinition()
    {
        Name = string.Empty;
        Type = string.Empty;
        Attr = string.Empty;
    }

    public bool Equals(ColumnDefinition other)
    {   
        return Name.Equals(other.Name) && Type.Equals(other.Type) && Attr.Equals(other.Attr);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object value)
    {
        return (value is ColumnDefinition) ? Equals(value as ColumnDefinition) : false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Name.GetHashCode() ^ Type.GetHashCode() ^ Attr.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Concat("{", Name, ":", Type, ":", Attr, "}");
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            MyMain(args);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public static void MyMain(string[] args)
    {
        var list1 = new []  
            { 
                new ColumnDefinition { Name = "foo", Type = "int", Attr = "0" }, 
                new ColumnDefinition { Name = "bar", Type = "int", Attr = "1" }, 
            };

        var list2 = new [] 
            { 
                new ColumnDefinition { Name = "foo", Type = "int", Attr = "0" }, 
                new ColumnDefinition { Name = "bar", Type = "string", Attr = "1" }, 
            };

        foreach (var changed in Enumerable.Except(list1, list2))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(changed);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I gave it a shot but it returns records when it shouldn't return anything in my test.

Comment: Have you implemented a proper equality comparer for your ColumnDefinition class? If not, please do. The Enumerable.Except/Intersect/Union functions depend on it.

Comment: Oh, I've never done that before.  I will give it a shot and see what I come with.  Thanks!

Comment: Typeseven, please see my edit above, is this how I would implement it?

Comment: Correct, but you also need to override void Equals(object) and int GetHashCode() for the ColumnDefinition class.

Comment: Since I have three properties do I need to have this line three times, once for each property?

int hashProductName = PropertyX == null ? 0 : PropertyX GetHashCode();

Comment: You may want to factor together the hashcodes for the relevant properties (those used in the equality comparer) such as: 

return ColName.GetHashCode() ^ ColType.GetHashCode() ^ ColAttributes.GetHashCode();

Comment: Added an all singing and dancing example =)